# Expand UITextView and then scroll after certain point

Tags: swift, autolayout, uitextview, uitextviewdelegate, cgsize

I have been struggling to set create this, I have read numerous posts on here, but do not understand what I am doing wrong.

I have a `UITextView`.

I would like it to expand in height, up to a number and then fix at that height with scrolling enabled.

I have set my `UITextFieldDelegate`and added the following -

```swift
    func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
        let newSize = textView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: 0, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))
        textView.frame.size = CGSize(width: 0, height: min(100, newSize.height))
    }
```

Doing this allow the to keep growing.

I'd now like it to stop and scroll instead at for example, a height of 100.

```swift
    func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
        let newSize = textView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: 0, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))

        let newHeight = min(100, newSize.height)

        textView.frame.size = CGSize(width: 0, height: newHeight)

        textView.isScrollEnabled = newHeight >= 100
    }
```

All that happens at this point is the scrollview shrinks when `isScrollEnabled` is set as `true`.

My textView is anchored only to `top`, `leading` and `trailing` of it's parent.

How can I force it to not collapse once scroll is enabled?

**EDIT**

I have added the following which works, however the text seems to 'wobble' when entering anything at the fixed height state

```swift
    func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
        let newSize = textView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: 0, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))

        let newHeight = min(100, newSize.height)

        textView.frame.size = CGSize(width: 0, height: newHeight)

        if newHeight >= 100 {
            textView.isScrollEnabled = true
            textView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
        } else {
            textView.isScrollEnabled = false
            textView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = false
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to make a default height constraint and connect it's outlet and play with it's constant

```
self.txH.constant = newHeight
self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
```